# Page cited for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

For each of my bibliographic entries, which I currently handle using bibtex, I would like to include the numbers of the pages of my document in which the entry is cited. For example:

```
James Terry. Programming for beginners. http://www.jterry.com. Cited on pages 5, 10, 11.
```

This means that this entry is cited on pages 5, 10, and 11 of my document.

Is there a command/package that would allow me to do this automatically?

Comment: Have a look at the questions tagged with [tag:back-referencing].

Comment: `\usepackage{citeref}` suffices.